# azure data factory: copy and zip data by definition from json

Tags: azure-data-factory

I'd like to copy multiple files in blob storage (from `00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001`) to one destination (`00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000`) and then zip entire container.
I have a following json definition which shows from where to where I'd like to copy the files.

```json
[
  {
    "from": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001/1.txt",
    "to": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001/1.txt"
  },
  {
    "from": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001/2.txt",
    "to": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000002/2.txt"
  },
  {
    "from": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001/3.txt",
    "to": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000003/3.txt"
  },
  {
    "from": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001/4.txt",
    "to": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000004/4.txt"
  },
  {
    "from": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001/5.txt",
    "to": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001/5.txt"
  },
  {
    "from": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001/6.txt",
    "to": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000002/6.txt"
  },
  {
    "from": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001/7.txt",
    "to": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000003/7.txt"
  },
  {
    "from": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001/8.txt",
    "to": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000004/8.txt"
  }
]
```

This file could be stored anywhere on blob storage so it shouldn't be that hard to read it. The thing I don't know is how can I read the file content and then for each entry `{from: .., to: ..}` copy the file to destination.

Comment: Are you reusing the directory for file 1.txt and 5.txt?

Comment: what do you mean by reusing? Multiple sources could be copied to the same target directory, but there could be 1..N target directories.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `lookup` activity to read the JSON file content and loop the files from the `lookup` activity to copy files from **source** to **destination**.

I tried with the 3 files and copied files from source to destination.

**Definition file:**

```
[
 {
  "from": "outbound/CSV1.csv",
  "to": "inbound/01/CSV1.csv"
 },
 {
  "from": "outbound/CSV2.csv",
  "to": "inbound/02/CSV2.csv"
 },
 {
  "from": "outbound/Inbound_file1.csv",
  "to": "inbound/01/Inbound_file1.csv"
 }
]
```

**Source files:**

[image]

***Azure Data factory pipeline:***

**1.** **Lookup activity:**

- Get the list of “**from**” and “**to**” paths from the definition file using lookup activity.

[image]

**Output of lookup activity:**

[image]

**2. ForEach activity:**

- Get the current item into the `foreach` loop from lookup output.

  ```
  @activity('Lookup1').output.value
  ```

[image]

**3. Source dataset:**

•   Create 2 dataset parameters to pass the folder and file dynamically from lookup output “from” path.

[image]

**4. Sink dataset:**

•   Create parameters in the sink dataset to pass the file path dynamically from lookup output “to” path.

[image]

**5. Copy activity:**

•   Pass the expressions as below to the dataset properties to get the Source file path in Source.

**Source_folder**: `@substring(item().from,0,indexof(item().from, '/'))`

**Source_filename**:`@substring(item().from,add(indexof(item().from,'/'),+1),sub(length(item().from),add(indexof(item().from, '/'),+1)))`

[image]

•   Pass the expressions as below to the dataset properties to get the sink file path in the sink.

**Sink_folder_path**: `@substring(item().to,0,indexof(item().to, '/'))`

**Sink_directory**:`@substring(item().to,add(indexof(item().to,'/'),1),sub(lastindexof(item().to, '/'),add(indexof(item().to, '/'),1)))`

**Sink_filename**:`@substring(item().to,add(lastindexof(item().to,'/'),1),sub(length(item().to),add(lastindexof(item().to, '/'),+1)))`

[image]

**Output**:

[image]

[image]

[image]

And for the zip container part, as per my knowledge, we cannot zip the entire container. I also did not find any supporting documents related to it. Instead, you can zip the file as below.

Ex: To zip the file you add the “.zip” extension to the file and add the compression type as required in the sink dataset.

[image]